# Get date in Italian Format as "Lunedì GG/MM" how to?

Tags: javascript, date

i've tried to do this :

```
    var curr = new Date; 
    var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay();  
    var last = first + 7; 
    var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first + 1)).toUTCString();
    var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(last)).toUTCString();
```

But i get firstday = "Mon, 18 Jan 2016 09:14:44 GMT" and
lastday = "Sun, 24 Jan 2016 09:14:44 GMT". How can i use italian name of the day and format DD/MM as "Lunedì 10/01" (Monday 10 of January in english).

Thanks
Cris

Comment: check this [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) out, it has "Multiple Locale Support"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without having to use external libraries, you want to use the `toLocaleString()` function.

```js
var options = {'weekday': 'long', 'month': '2-digit', 'day': '2-digit'};
var date = new Date().toLocaleString('it-IT', options);

document.write(date)
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) with all the possible options

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply but "Code Snippet" doesn't work... :(

Comment: @CristianCapannini I fixed it like 30 secs ago :)

Let me know if the last version works, it correctly prints 'giovedì 21/01' in my browser

Comment: but i'm just in doubt if i have the date as '23/01/2016' how can i obtain it?

Comment: @CristianCapannini that's a non standard date, I suggest you to use an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date in your code, until you have to show it.

It's not a good idea to store date object in a non standard format.

Otherwise, if you **strictly** need to start from the format you suggested, use moment.js or build a regex parser...

Answer (score 3):

Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs) for that

```js
moment.locale('it');
document.write(moment().format('dddd DD/MM'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/locale/it.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you can do it by using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) ,By default, Moment.js comes with English locale strings. If you need other locales, you can load them into Moment.js like this:

```
 moment.locale('it');
var currentDate =  moment();
//fist
alert(moment().format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss'));
//last
alert(currentDate.add(7, 'days').format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss'));
```

this a [working demo](http://codepen.io/aitnasser/pen/gPoogL)

Answer (score 0):

with this approach you can craft every custom format:

```js
function italianTimeFormat (dateUTC) {
  if (dateUTC) {
    let jsDateFormat = new Date(dateUTC)
    let fullStringTime = {
      day: Number(jsDateFormat.getDate() < 10) ? '0' + jsDateFormat.getDate() : jsDateFormat.getDate(),
      month: Number((jsDateFormat.getMonth() + 1)) < 10 ? '0' + (jsDateFormat.getMonth() + 1) : (jsDateFormat.getMonth() + 1),
      year: jsDateFormat.getFullYear(),
      hours: Number(jsDateFormat.getHours()) < 10 ? '0' + jsDateFormat.getHours() : jsDateFormat.getHours(),
      minutes: Number(jsDateFormat.getMinutes()) < 10 ? '0' + jsDateFormat.getMinutes() : jsDateFormat.getMinutes()
    }
    return fullStringTime.day + '/' + fullStringTime.month + '/' + fullStringTime.year + ' ' +
      fullStringTime.hours + ':' + fullStringTime.minutes
  }
  return null
}
let today = Date.now();
document.write(italianTimeFormat(today))
```

I hope i've been helpful for someone